# My dual-boot PC boots directly into Windows since I upgraded my Ubuntu to 20.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, boot-repair, grub-efi

I've been using Ubuntu 19.10 and Windows 10 on my device with dualboot. Recently, I upgraded Ubuntu to 20.04 LTS, and since then, my PC skips GRUB and boots directly to Windows 10.

To solve this, I tried using Boot Repair and chose the Recommended Repair option, which did its thing and gave me the following pastebin URL.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hR6yjGfXqc/

However, my PC still directly boots Windows 10, and there's unfortunately no way to access Ubuntu.

At the end of the linked report, it says:

```
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your BIOS.
If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

But I don't know how to do that. My PC has EFI, not legacy BIOS.

Could you please help?

Thanks in advance,

Silacko

Comment: It says grub was re-installed with no error and reset boot order to Ubuntu first. See original line 725 and updated in 1156. Windows updates will reset to make Windows first, just as grub updates or reinstall will make grub first in boot order. Some computers like HP do not support boot order changes except thru your UEFI settings (not the UEFI boot menu). Otherwise you should be able to boot Ubuntu or Windows  from UEFI boot menu, often f12, check you manual.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Firmware settings (Usually `F2` during boot). In boot sequence move `Ubuntu` above `Windows boot manager`. This will solve your issue.